# How integrate SQL server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sql-server-2008

Hi I'm trying to configure SQL Server in Eclipse because the DB is on a remote machine and I need to use desktop remote and use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
Because we are more then one to use this machine I'm wondering if is possible to use Eclipse to navigate in the DB.

I need to know how create a new Database Connection where download the driver for SQL Server R 2008 and how configure the wizard *New Connection Profile* in Eclipse.

Thanks a million
Carlo

Comment: Why do you need to connect Eclipse to the db if you just stated you are going to use SSMS?

Comment: Because I'm using Mac on my machine and to use SSMS I need to connect by Remote Desktop.